# Shopify-Limit products is setted so when clients click cart button with over quantity, they get error

Tags: shopify, shopify-template, shopify-api-node

I'm shopify developer.
I want to set quantity limit so that if client try to add over limit quantity and click "cart" button, they get error message.
How can I implement this?
Thanks for seeing my question.

Answer (score 0):

When you render a product, you have access to its current quantity. You are free to use this value. Take the example of a widget with 3 variants, A, B and C. A has 3, B has 6, and C has 9.

When you render your input element to capture quantity, you are aware of the variant in question, and the max quantity allowed (at the time the page rendered anyway). So you are free to limit the quantity to be less than the maximum available using simple HTML controls. With Javascript you can script this kind of stuff.

In the end though, by the time the customer reaches checkout, if say they asked for 3 of B, even though at that time B had 6, so 3 was good and allowed, at checkout, Shopify may reject their order as B may only have 2 at that time. Meaning they waited too long to purchase.

If Shopify did not work this way, people would hold inventory hostage while not buying. So in effect, even if you limit quantities, your customers may still be unable to purchase all they want.

Long story short, you can add quantity limits to the HTML element used to change the quantity going into the cart. Use the variant's current quantity from Shopify as the high limit.